# How to pass array 2d as parameter from function and return array 2d this function?

Tags: c++

The problem in question involves an iterative process in which the object "am" changes with this process (loop). So, I need to create a "res" object that will store the results of the Tfunc function to be used in the same process in another procedure. However, I can not do that. I'm a good beginner in C ++ programming. I'm a programmer in the R language.

My operational system is ubuntu 16.04 using ide codeblocks.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

const int k = 3;

double Tfunc(double Told[k][k], double amm, int K);

int sample(int x);

int main(){
 int i, j;
 double am = 50;
 double told[k][k]{
  {1,0,0},
  {0,1,0},
  {0,0,1}
};

  double res;

  res = Tfunc(told, am, k);

  for(i=0;i<k;i++){
      for(j=0;j<k;j++){
          cout << res[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}

double Tfunc(double Told[k][k], double amm, int K)
{
 int id1;
 int id2;
 int id3;

 id1 = sample(K);
 id2 = sample(K);
 id3 = sample(K);

 while(id2 == id3){
  id3 = sample(K);
 }

 Told[id1][id2] = Told[id1][id2] + amm;
 Told[id1][id3] = Told[id1][id3] - amm;

 return Told;
}

int sample(int x)
{
 srand(time(NULL)); //initialize the random seed

 int RandIndex = rand() % (x); 
 return RandIndex;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` instead. Find a tutorial on how use standard library containers such as `vector`.

Comment: It's probably easier to use a `std::array<std::array<double,k>>` to do this. `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` is another (more flexible) alternative.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Agree, `std::array` is much more efficient here and applicable because fixed size. Just a note. s/b `std::array<std::array<double,k>,k>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, and, maybe this is one of the root causes of your problem, you are not passing the 2 dimensional array to your subfunction correctly.

You could pass it as reference or as pointer. Then you could also modify the array, given as parameter, in your subfunction.

Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

Then, in modern C++ you would use STL containers for your puposes. And for 2 dimensional stuff, you need to create a container of containers. So a std::vector of std::vector, or a std::array of std::array.

The Tfunc will return that container-container and make usage of RVO (Return Value Optimization). So there is no loss in complexity.

I created an example file for you. This is just one possible solution. There are many.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

constexpr size_t MatrixDimension = 3;
using DoubleArray = std::array<double, MatrixDimension>;
using Matrix = std::array<DoubleArray, MatrixDimension>;

constexpr Matrix StartMatrix{{
 {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
 {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
 {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
}};

size_t randomIndex()
{
    std::random_device randomDevice;    // Obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 randomGenerator(randomDevice());  // Seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> distribution(0, MatrixDimension-1); // Range
    return distribution(randomGenerator);
}

Matrix Tfunc(const Matrix& givenMatrix, double amm)
{
    size_t index1{ randomIndex() }; // Set indices with random values
    size_t index2{ randomIndex() };
    size_t index3{ randomIndex() };

    while (index2 == index3) {          // Make sure that index 2 is not equal index 3
        index3 = randomIndex();
    }
    Matrix calculatedMatrix{};

    calculatedMatrix[index1][index2] = givenMatrix[index1][index2] + amm;
    calculatedMatrix[index1][index3] = givenMatrix[index1][index3] - amm;

    return calculatedMatrix;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr double amm{ 50.0 };
    Matrix result = Tfunc(StartMatrix, amm);  // Apply Tfunc to matrix

    // Debug Output.  Print matrix to std::cout
    std::for_each(result.begin(), result.end(), [](DoubleArray &da) {std::copy(da.begin(), da.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; });

    return 0;
}
```

BTW. I do not know the purpose of your program. But I think you want to have 3 different indices in TFunc. This is not guaranteed. 2 can be the same.

I hope this helps . . .

Comment: Hi Armin. Thanks a lot for the help. I tried to run your code and realized that it went into an infinite loop. Placing in the main function only "std :: cout << randomIndex ();", I noticed that the same number is always generated. I tried to get around but I could not because of my experience with the language. If I still can help, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem, but I could not. I created a main with a loop and printed 100 times "randomIndex()" and got a different number any time. I am afraid that without seeing you code, I cannot help.